# Efficient approach for finding unused hashes in Content Security Policy (CSP)

Tags: web-applications, create-react-app, content-security-policy

As it has grown, a web app project I am working on has collected a number of different Content-Security-Policy (CSP) hashes for script, styles, etc.

Example:

```
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="
      media-src 'self'; 
      font-src 'self'; 
      frame-src 'self'; 
      form-action 'none'; 
      manifest-src 'self'; 
      base-uri 'self'; 
      img-src https://abc.def.gh/p/ https://zzz.cloudfront.net/ https://yyy.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com 'self' data:; 
      object-src 'self'; 
      script-src 'self' 'sha216-R7Zr1v1pcU1Va9footCb8OXwaCCHv3jo4u9n021PzvU=' 'sha216-D6kpIX0A4ZZbarxfEpOpkS2C/u3VZN/Hbjf0UwftoVz=' sha216-FfE0MdzfbazOkCJJ47YDLRzxvB/EZcvSmfZFRzlCKRI=' 'sha216-yt+SNVxzipi6H6yb7ndFuZM1ssXM9esz4UpRHaTsyVk=' 'sha216-N6UIysWrwcYvmXstzin14XIifb70T2Lo/6Vy9ZO/4T0='  'sha216-ZWEWYY8lyjmZf4d/SNJ2Kukcs9BRiM3oy/Z0Fu6H2W0='; 
      style-src 'self' 'sha216-zyizjojoVtf8M2FT8jNLfs+CYkzyv/ZEF6AIuc1XoZI=' 'sha216-49ReRph8b8Sa+/mftW+1JCeuRfRkm1NMpJWZZ3hSuFU=' 'sha216-zx9ISFmdz7Rbd/NftaHMO29ZyoarWzn6dKOnrf6ouwE=' 'sha216-XAds8kbI6klLZtzB1BxSaYeyhhnHWCW00jUti7fkfU0=' 'sha216-h2EKlwSNim3MRhd8OYl8eo7M9zBOreffv/J2kra3+uc=' 'sha216-hatsupTjpio1IsCRvz2hSbC/+Z8bzWRpjXvllh4k8fA=' 'sha216-XCRtr1swisjWbTN2AKYCE11fvirswddoChARA916u2E=' 'sha216-Z3n1JddbKnronPZzprVjXNr99pfHo1S/HzY8AAYxDfM=' 'sha216-mkh8131AFt6ozczZfol78HZzvhZZEDTCXpPucFH37Jo=' 'sha216-pTe3Cr9vCAnZHKzzJejJetoJldnZHyw4dEXiPu1NBFI=' 'sha216-4hY4C7xfXajWIFTjNT/zk/RrluseiIYurzSXI1F3BUs=' 'sha216-3uCwhoisu0Kod9sdEJzoyVarjupI7pd94ERLvrW3Jdc=' 'sha216-SkXkmil/4eLkT7Y++BtAATntLsJ8Oe1DudZeKVpOE6U=' 'sha216-ecme12345njkZJmkNKy6Owvp2pLOS6LP18KXkZ7kzpI=' 'sha216-l7Zurd123Kt1uP/FWihho9JI/u0bEsIkfWlFD9YXPYs=' 'sha216-xW6foUSLlN7BDvMm901ljDa3Pa9r1RRCRC1ckX1d6Xc=' 'sha216-ERdEUYbwc1239xHFULzUmscpMord1CMZ+UPfEtumKvc=' 'sha216-/zr1/uyE2uUPKLlJKYXFblnI0K9844f9Slzr8XjLUaM=' 'sha216-uaCrzJrc0cTRU123ENCDv7+KBrFSmL9bkyYMia/z2dA=' 'sha216-1FfZW2ZRtJzysZKiIO1YCczI1GGG123BaJyMT34m+ic=' 'sha216-Bo478sW+t1123H1xMPaDZATjJljH6N3toneejOxCZz0=' 'sha216-12t0bJPIyxfs/RrsW8RE3JJJERKnHL2RyzHBzJvEanc=' 'sha216-4444OUmPCB+n8D4LZBlrjat93cyt8usmzZETr1Z6Jxc='; 
      connect-src 'self' https://not.us https://is.us/oauth/token https://back.example.com https://www.example.com https://example.com https://aabbcc.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com https://sings-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com;"
    />
```

Our current mechanism for determining unused hashes is to remove a hash from the CSP directives and check if the browser throws an error; this approach is inefficient.

Is there a more efficient or automated way of doing this?

How are others maintaining large CSPs?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add a Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only header with the same content and report-uri or report-to directive pointing to a report endpoint, but without the hashes. Let it run for a while (time depends on how much site is used) and then check the reporting service. Remove all hashes that haven't had reports.

Comment: This is an interesting approach — I am going to try using a *Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only* and see if we can adapt this towards a solution. @Halvor Sakshaug Have you used CSP reports for this purpose?

Comment: I haven't used it for this exact purpose, but I have considered using it for cleaning up unused sources, but due to the site being phased out I didn't have to. I have used it a lot for testing out new policies before taking effect and for other non-standard cases like finding content loaded over http causing mixed content and detecting usages of framing.

Comment: thank you for this idea; so far after using this strategy for a few months it doesn't feel like it offers us efficiency. The report feel cumbersome to use with minified code. Curious, have you used `report-uri` in a production/minified context? I would add that it has been *extremely* helpful in figuring out unusual CSP issues we have with unique browser/device scenarios! 

Comment: I haven't used it much inline scripts, mainly for other sources.